audio unsetting itself after I start running game in unity
Basically, I have a series of objects with health, and each one I want to emit a sound when hit.
public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 3;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    public void Damage(int amount)
    {
        this.health -= amount;
        this.audioSource.Play();

    }


when I run this code, I get a Null Reference error every time I try and hit something. basically, I've defined the audio source in the inspector, but when I actually run the game, the inspector empties out that audio source and thus returns a Null Reference error.
I have no clue why it's doing that. Does anyone know what might be going on?

is this on something that has an audiosource?

yes, an audio source is attached as a child to the game object

then this does not have an audiosource the child does, and you havent said find it on a child, so its returning null

thank you so much!! this game is due for my class tomorrow and this problem was really plaguing me,, i appreciate your help :)
